# Copy Rows from one SQL Server database to another when table changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a method to copy rows from selected table from one SQL database to another whenever a change happens to those selected tables. Our client has a live database and needs to fetch changes to our database associated with new website.

We are planning to implement triggers on those selected tables which will invoke the coping mechanism. Please tell me if this will cause any performance issues, and recommend if any suggested method for the same.

Comment: Yes, triggers will **always** cause a slight performance decrease - and it can be quite massive if the triggers aren't written very carefully, very efficiently. You should look at things like replication or [AlwaysOn](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/sql-server-2012-alwayson/) features, if you have the Enterprise edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replication will be good solution.As your requirements are not getting clear from your question still check this link 
[https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/715550/SQL-Server-Replication-Step-by-Step]

Comment: Thanks for your suggested solution.  However SQL Server Replication is high level distributed system, where data automatically distributed from a source database to one or more recipient databases. Hence we need to analyses whether  to go for this approach for our current 'one-off synchronization' ( single table data from one db to proposed new site db) based on the project requirement scope.